# wxWidgets BoxSizer not expanding to full width

Tags: c++, layout, wxwidgets

Ok so I have a question about some wxWidgets sizers and how I thought they were supposed to act but aren't acting...

[image: Minimum size]

[image: Bigger size]

My set up for these images is like so:

```
verticalBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
serverBarBox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

serverBarBox->Add(serverEntry, 5);
serverBarBox->Add(portEntry, 1);

verticalBox->Add(serverBarBox, wxEXPAND);
```

Now I thought that the serverBarBox would expand to take up the full width however it doesn't. How is it that I would achieve such a thing with the wxBoxSizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `wxEXPAND` as a proportion, not as a flag that it is.

To avoid such problems, prefer to use much more clear [wxSizerFlags](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer_flags.html) instead of passing all sizer parameters directly. E.g. rewriting your code above with it gives

```
serverBarBox->Add(serverEntry, wxSizerFlags().Proportion(5));
serverBarBox->Add(portEntry, wxSizerFlags().Proportion(1));

verticalBox->Add(serverBarBox, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
```

Comment: To combine them just use `wxSizerFlags().Expand().Proportion(1)`